# Nothing visible on toggle dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

I have navigation bar which works fine but when in mobile view the toggle button appears but it shows no choices on drop down. I have been looking and trying through available answers but nothing is helping. Can someone look in below code and point out some problem if there is . Thanks a lot.

```
      <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top " role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li class="main-nav-link hidden-sm hidden-xs ">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'fosssite:home' %}">HOME</a>
                </li>
                <li class="main-nav-link hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'fosssite:events' %}">EVENTS</a></a>
                </li>
                <li class="main-nav-link hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'fosssite:contributions' %}">CONTRIBUTIONS</a>
                </li>
                <li class="main-nav-link hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'fosssite:blog' %}">BLOG</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            {% block profile %}
            {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                <li>
                    <a class="nav-link"  href="{% url 'fosssite:profileuser' name=request.user %}">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Welcome {{ request.user }}</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'fosssite:edit_user_profile' name=request.user %}">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit Profile</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'fosssite:logout' %}">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            {% else %}
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                <li class="main-nav-link">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'fosssite:UserFormView'%}">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>SIGN UP</a>
                </li>
                <li class="main-nav-link">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'fosssite:login_user' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> LOGIN</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            {% endif %}

            {% endblock %}
            </ul>

        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: to start after EVENTS you have 2 end </a> tags

Comment: @mlegg made the correction nothing happened

Comment: @mlegg Solved it, I removed hidden-sm and hidden-xs from list and now it works fine